# Is it simple to overpost an Edit controller even though you use a ViewModel in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've learned to use ViewModels to protect my controllers from overposting attacks.  However, take this example I see a lot:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var dbModel = db.Models.Find(viewModel.Id);

        // ... bind viewModel properties to dbModel... but don't bind Id

        db.Entry(dbModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Yes, you are not binding the Id... but can't you overpost `viewModel.Id` to `Find` and change a different `dbModel` than intended? If so, is there a simple way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue of over posting was addressed in Scott`s post [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETOverpostingMassAssignmentModelBindingSecurity.aspx). To quote:

> How do we fix the problem? Well, a few ways. You can mark the property
> as [ReadOnly]. More commonly, you can use a BindAttribute on the
> method parameters and just include (whitelist) the properties you want
> to allow for binding:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult>> Create([Bind("First,Last")] Person person)
```

> Or, the correct answer.
> Don't let models that look like this get anywhere near the user. This
> is the case for ViewModels. Make a model that looks like the View.
> Then do the work. You can make the work easier with something like
> AutoMapper.
>
> Some folks find ViewModels to be too cumbersome for basic
> stuff. That's valid. There are those that are "All ViewModels All The
> Time," but I'm more practical. Use what works, use what's appropriate,
> but know what's happening underneath so you don't get some
> scriptkiddie overposting to your app and a bit getting flipped in your
> Model as a side effect.

Comment: I get that on a Create type action where a ViewModel can prevent this by just not giving the `Id`.  But on an `Edit` type action, the `POST` has to know the `Id` you're editing.  So if I just declare that it doesn't bind, it can't be modified on `POST` and will return the same `Id` that was given in the `GET` request? It's that simple?

Comment: Over posting means that a value that was not meant to sent by the user is sent anyway. In an typical update operation, the id *is* expected so this is not over posting, but another attack. To prevent that, its possible to use temporary id values generated specifically for the current session. Also authorizing a user to specific id`s can help , if theres an authentication scheme in place

Answer (score 0):

That's why it's good practice to add the id as a parameter to the action (and checking to see if it's the same as the id in the model). This, combined with an anti-forgery token should normally keep you safe.

Please also have a look at:
- [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)
- [Preventing mass assignment or over posting in ASP.NET Core](https://andrewlock.net/preventing-mass-assignment-or-over-posting-in-asp-net-core/)